# Grade of Service Probability Function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematics, statistics, scipy

Consider the following typical probability scenario:

[image: Probability Scenario]

I defined this function to handle that scenario, I'm curious if Python has a more efficient method to handle this, or if this is the best way:

```
from scipy.special import binom

def grade_of_service(n, p, c):
    prob = 0
    k = c + 1
    while k <= n:
        prob += binom(n, k)*(p**k)*((1-p)**(n-k))
        k += 1
    return prob
```

EDIT: Here's an example solution from the author of this example:  "If n = 100, p=0.1, and c=15, the probability of interest turns out to be 0.0399."
My probability does round to this result.  But due to the roundoff error / numerical precision, it doesn't seem to matter if k = n or k = n+1.

Comment: Do you have some example inputs we can test with? Preferably edge cases.

Comment: @Peilonrayz, I edited to provide an example solution from the example author.  I don't have any edge cases yet but will mess with some numbers to see if I can find some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pure Python

1. You should use a `for` loop rather than a while loop.
2. You can use a generator comprehension to build all `prob`'s.
3. You can use `sum` to get the sum.

```
def grade_of_service(n, p, c):
    return sum(binom(n, k)*(p**k)*((1-p)**(n-k)) for k in range(c+1, n+1))
```

## Numpy and friends

1. Use `numpy.arange` rather than `range`.
2. Write out the equation same as above, just not in a comprehension.
3. Change `sum` to `numpy.sum`.

```
import numpy


def grade_of_service(n, p, c):
    k = numpy.arange(c+1, n+1)
    return numpy.sum(binom(n, k)*(p**k)*((1-p)**(n-k)))
```

This has a problem with numbers that exceed a certain size, as numpy numbers are finite.

Comment: Thank you this will be more efficient in the case the variables get incredibly large, the generator will save me a lot of memory usage. In practical use if the probability meets a threshold is really all that matters, so as long as the precision is down to .001 it probably won’t make a difference. Since they are probabilities they will never exceed 1, and anything below .01 in practice probably doesn’t need to be that precise.